# In D3, it possible to add elements to a group AFTER those elements have already been created?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

From what I've seen in both Scott Murray's book and lurking S/O, first the "g" group is created, and following this, the elements that belong to the group are appended.

I'm wondering, however — is it possible to add elements to a group **after** they've already been created?

I've got a number of circles drawn onto my svg, and I want to contain each grouping of circles, by colour (I'd group them by class, but in this case, it's not an option because I'm using common classes for mouseover effects), in order to manipulate these groups visually later.

If this so, how would this look like?

e.g., how would one add the following selection of elements to a group?

```
svg.selectAll("[style *= 'rgb(10, 20, 30)']")
```

**EDIT**:  From [another similar S/O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713928/can-i-move-an-svg-element-between-svg-groups-in-d3-js), I can see how to work with a single element. My issue, however, is that I'm confused regarding how I should do this with *several elements*.

Comment: @Lars, the answer I've duplicated seems to work well for single elements, but what's the best way to follow through if I'm selecting numerous circles? Is there a way to do this in D3, or is this a question of hacking my way through using JS?

Comment: For multiple elements just use a loop: `removed.each(function() { yourTargetGroup.append(this); })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, sorry to keep bringing this up — I had initially thought I'd worked things out, but no dice — I'm getting an `n.indexOf is not a function` error. I've uploaded the code to a block, [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/aa1f7e8abb2ad3a66e65), but can't quite seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong (the circles of the darkest brown don't show up because of this error; the remove/add code is lines 138-140). Is this sort of thing familiar to you?

Comment: Right ok, you need to return the element in a function to `.append()` -- http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/63a472bcf01f95c36f38

Comment: @LarsKotthoff That works perfectly, thanks for all the help!