# ungrouping an element in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, grouping

It seems to me that there is no native function to ungroup an element in D3.
So, I tried to remove the element from the group and thern recreate the element by append method, using this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713928/can-i-move-an-svg-element-between-svg-groups-in-d3-js) answer.

Unfortunately my code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wy78/27/)) contains (at least) an error. I cannot understand what is.

[create four red circles, then change the color of the first one from red to green after having detached it from the group of all the circles]

```
    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];

    var group=svg.append("g");
    var circles = group.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("r",function(d){ return d })
    .attr("cx",function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 })
    .attr("cy",50)
    .attr("fill",'red');

    var circle=circles.select("circle");
    var removed = circle.remove();
    var newcircle=svg.append(function() {
        return removed.node();
    });
    d3.select(newcircle).attr("fill","green");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You try to select a circle from the `circles` selection. However, this would select a **sub**-element of the circles in that selection, which does not make any sense. Instead of

   ```
   var circle = circles.select("circle");
   ```

   you want

   ```
   var circle = group.select("circle");
   ```

   This way you select the circle from the group.
2. `newCircle` already is a d3 selection object. It is an error re-select by doing `d3.select(newcircle)`. The code should look like

   ```
   newcircle.attr("fill", "green");
   ```

Putting this all together you end up with something as follows:

```js
   var svg = d3.select('svg');

   var dataSet = [10, 20, 30, 40];

   var group  =svg.append("g");
   var circles = group.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dataSet)
    .enter().append('circle')
      .attr("r",function(d){ return d })
      .attr("cx",function(d, i){ return i * 100 + 50 })
      .attr("cy",50)
      .attr("fill",'red');

   var circle = group.select("circle");
   var removed = circle.remove();
   var newcircle = svg.append(function() {
     return removed.node();
   });
   newcircle.attr("fill", "green");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>

<svg width="600" height="200"></svg>
```