# Reorder group elements to a specific order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have multiple groups inside another group and i want to reorder them in a specific order.

```
<svg>
    <g id="wrapper">
        <g id="b">...</g>
        <g id="a">...</g>
        <g id="c">...</g>
        <g id="e">...</g>
        <g id="d">...</g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Each groups inside the wrapper group has an id, right now the order of the ids are b, a, c, e, d. Say i want to order it with an array `[3, 1, 4, 5, 2]` then the corresponding order will be c, b, e, d, a.

Resulting in,

```
<svg>
    <g id="wrapper">
        <g id="c">...</g>
        <g id="b">...</g>
        <g id="e">...</g>
        <g id="d">...</g>
        <g id="a">...</g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can remove and append the groups according to your desired order. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713928/can-i-move-an-svg-element-between-svg-groups-in-d3-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 has a very handy method, named [sort()](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_sort). Unfortunately, for this method to work, you have to compare the *data* bound to each element, and they have none right now. If you don't want to bind a bogus data you can always use pure JavaScript for this.

So, for using `selection.sort()`, we'll first bind the data based on your index array (pay attention to the fact that the indices in your array are not zero based):

```
const order = [3, 1, 4, 5, 2];
const groups = d3.selectAll("#wrapper g");
groups.each(function(_, i) {
  d3.select(this).datum({
    position: i + 1
  })
});
```

Or just:

```
const order = [3, 1, 4, 5, 2];
const groups = d3.selectAll("#wrapper g");
groups.datum(function(_, i) {
  return {
    position: i + 1
  }
});
```

After that, it's just a matter of:

```
groups.sort(function(a, b) {
  return order.indexOf(a.position) - order.indexOf(b.position)
});
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const order = [3, 1, 4, 5, 2];
const groups = d3.selectAll("#wrapper g");
groups.datum(function(_, i) {
  return {
    position: i + 1
  }
});
groups.sort(function(a, b) {
  return order.indexOf(a.position) - order.indexOf(b.position)
});

console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select("svg").node()))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
    <g id="wrapper">
        <g id="b"></g>
        <g id="a"></g>
        <g id="c"></g>
        <g id="e"></g>
        <g id="d"></g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And this is the result, if you inspect the SVG:

```
<svg>
    <g id="wrapper">
        <g id="c"></g>
        <g id="b"></g>
        <g id="e"></g>
        <g id="d"></g>
        <g id="a"></g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Would this considered be a slow or inefficient method if my actual case has a lot of different wrapper groups to sort?

Comment: @tomc well, there is no doubt that pure JS is faster. The question is, would that difference be important/noticeable in your case?

Comment: Thanks, I think this will be sufficient for my case.